# Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, velocity

I was searching for a Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse Luna but I could not find any. I found couple of editor plugins like:

1. [Veloeclipse](http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/)
2. [Velocity Editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/veloedit/)
3. [Veloedit](http://veloedit.sourceforge.net/)       <--------------- **This is now working on Luna 4.4.1!**
4. [QIQU](http://www.aloba.ch/qiqu/downloads_en.html)
5. [Velocity Web Edit](http://velocitywebedit.sourceforge.net/)

None of this worked for Eclipse Luna. Does anyone else know any other plugin for editing Velocity files in Eclipse Luna?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Veloedit installs in Luna but it doesn't run in Luna or Mars. There's a fix in the comments to replace the jar that does get it to work though. For me I put this in ${HOME}/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2_375726925_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins   Hopefully it will be updated! http://sourceforge.net/p/veloedit/bugs/12/#0e8a

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install support for 2.0 style plugins using Help > Install New Software.

Select the 'Eclipse Project Updates' site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4).

You will find 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' in the 'Eclipse Tests, Examples and Extras' section.

Install it.

After, simply install [Veloeclipse](http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/) or other old "2.0 style" plugin

Comment: I can confirm that this answer also works for Eclipse Mars. Regarding the different editors veloeclipse provides syntax highlighting for HTML as well as velocity, whereas veloedit only highlights velocity.

Comment: I did not find Veloeclipse in marketplace after installing 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support'.

Comment: You have to add the update site manually, as per the Veloeclipse link by Dmitriy: http://veloeclipse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/update/
How to add a software site: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-127.htm

Comment: Google Code was closed some time ago, and the only option to get the code of the project now is to download it as Subversion working copy archive: [https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/veloeclipse/source-archive.zip](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/veloeclipse/source-archive.zip). You can try use extracted archive as a source of plugin with Eclipse "Install New Software", but cannot guarantee success, sorry. // This year i've moved to Idea with its built-in plugin that works great!

Answer (score 3):

Veloedit worked, following the installation instructions from their github page:  https://github.com/vaulttec/veloedit

> **Installation**
>
> Online updates are available from
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaulttec/veloedit/updatesite/.
>   Define a site bookmark in Eclipse's Update Manager view,
>   navigate to the update site via this bookmark and install
>   the Velocity UI feature.

Answer (score 1):

Veloedit seems the most prominent option for file editing, but it has installation problems currently. More information about the current status in active [SourceForge bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/veloedit/bugs/12/).

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that installing 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' made the plugin work in Eclipse Luna. Thanks.