# eclipse Mars default Velocity editor

Tags: eclipse, velocity, eclipse-mars

I accidentally associated VM files with EditPadPro and I want to revert.

What was the eclipse Mars default Velocity Editor?  I can't see anything obvious in the File Associations dropdown.

Was it just Text Editor?  If so I will find a plugin for VMs  a la:
[Velocity editor plugin for Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26384762/velocity-editor-plugin-for-eclipse-luna)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse donot have intergrated editor for .vm files.You can install plugin to edit it.There are some choices for you:Veloeclipse、VeloEdit....  But I donot know if these plugins can installed and used in the lasted version Eclipse.